# How to fill in null values in 1st row using values in 2nd row?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to write a query that shows only the 1st rows for each name, but those rows have a null for the title, so I want to pull in their titles from the immediate next row.

table1

| Name | Title | Row |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dan | NULL | 1 |
| Dan | Engineer | 2 |
| Dan | Developer | 3 |
| Jay | NULL | 1 |
| Jay | Lawyer | 2 |

The final result should look like the following:

| Name | Title | Row |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dan | Engineer | 1 |
| Jay | Lawyer | 1 |

I've only written this so far, I don't know how to pull in the titles from the previous row. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
select *
from table1
where Row = 1
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution using the lead( ) window function.

```
SELECT Name, IFNULL(Title, LeadTitle), Row
FROM (
  SELECT Name, Title, LEAD(Title) OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY ROW) AS LeadTitle, Row
  FROM `dataset.tablename` )
WHERE Row = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT 
  T1.Name, 
  (CASE WHEN T1.Title IS NULL 
        THEN (SELECT TOP(1) T2.Title FROM table1 T2 WHERE T2.Name = T1.Name AND T2.Title IS NOT NULL ORDER BY T2.Row ASC) ELSE T1.Title END) AS 'Title', 
  T1.Row
FROM table1 T1
WHERE T1.Row = 1
```

The query checks if the Title is NULL and in that case selects first title for that name that's not NULL otherwise returns Title of 1st row.

Comment: I got the following error "Scalar subquery produced more than one element"

Comment: Sorry ... I corrected query now - there was limiter TOP(1) missing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the simplest way to achieve this is by grouping and excluding any rows having null value.

`select * from table1 where Title IS NOT NULL GROUP BY Name`

Should work like a charm

Comment: That's not the goal of the query though, I am trying to capture the rows with the null values and only replace the nulls. Filtering out those rows defeats the whole purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Use below approach

```
select name, lead(title) over win as title, row
from your_table
qualify 1 = row_number() over win
window win as (partition by name order by row)
```

if applied to sample data in your question  output is

[image]